# Multiple list comprehension actions in a single line

Tags: python, string, list, list-comprehension

I am currently performing the following actions to make a list lowercase then remove the dots.

```
lowercase_list = [x.lower() for x in my_list]
lowercase_stripped_list = [x.replace('.', '') for x in lowercase_list]
```

is there a way to do this in a single line?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chain the method calls ([`str.lower`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) returns a string, you can call another string method [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) on the return value):

```
>>> my_list = ['Hello. World', 'Big.Big.World']
>>> [x.lower().replace('.', '') for x in my_list]
['hello world', 'bigbigworld']
```

Comment: @JamesPatrickBurke, Welcome to Stack Overflow! If this helped you, you can tell the community so by [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5235).

Comment: will do, apparently not allowed to do so for 7 minutes - i guess thats to avoid gaming?